# How does one go about finding out who the good instructors are?

Tags: professorship

I am an incoming freshman. I'd like the first set of courses I pick to be with great professors. By great I mean someone that's encouraging, honest, and patient, and that makes the subject interesting.

My question is: How should I go about finding who these professors are?

Comment: Check out their profile an do a little social analysis on their students.

Comment: Nobody's mentioned ratemyprofessors.com yet? It's out there, but I'll only mention it with a caveat: undergraduate students can be notoriously fickle as a group, often resenting what's fair, or best for them in the long run. Some professors get lower ratings mostly because they challenge students. Other times, students will use a forum like that as a place to vent, because of a single peeve or a simple miscommunication. If you decide to use a site like that one, take what you find there with a grain of salt, and learn to read between the lines. No one pleases all the people all the time.

Comment: This question applies to grad students equally.

Comment: At my institution you could look at their profile and see what courses they taught for the term. Look for the ones doing active research, talk to them outside of class, and get to know them. Get in on research experiences, internships and coops, networking experiences, etc. early on and develop a good rapport early in. This is how you end up on excellent terms for grad school, in addition to good grades. By doing this you will learn what professors you like, and your experiences should hopefully make the subject interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At most US institutions (and perhaps in other countries as well), the first week or two of classes are what's known as an "add/drop" period, in which you can switch from one class to another before you're "locked in" to the classes you're going to take for the semester.  This means that if there's a professor you're not sure about, you can attend a class or two with them and get a feel for whether their classroom style and their personality are compatible with your preferences.

A lot of professors don't particularly care for this approach from their students—a student who comes into the class a week late will be substantially behind, and may require special attention to get them caught up.  But it may reassure you to know that you have this option in your back pocket should you discover that one of your professors is truly awful.

Comment: Do note that some professors (I don't know how many) are sticklers and won't let you do any makeup work if you add late. This stung me once when I added an introductory course late, and immediately had three weeks of lab and homework scores zeroed.

Answer (score 1):

Easy: Ask your sophomore/junior/senior friends. Depending on the institution, teaching evluations may also be publicly available.

Comment: *Incoming* freshmen frequently haven't yet met any current students of the institution, so I wouldn't assume an incoming freshman has any sophomore/junior/senior friends.

Comment: @NateEldredge I searched for them. By the time I started, I already knew a few present and former students.